# Block or drop DNS requests within forwarded packets

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, dns

I have a default Debian 9 installed in minipc, which is forwarding packets further.

I wish to be able to block hosts via domains, means if any forwarded packet of DNS type has request for example of youtube.com, it should be dropped.
I know there are methods to drop them within iptables rules, but it is not advised technique.

I am afraid that setting dnsmasq or bind wont work, since few computers has google's 8.8.8.8 DNS server hardcoded (Few IoT devices).

So is there a way to either:

- force DNS resolving via my dnsmasq/bind (so i can setup a blacklist)
- drop DNS request packets containing 'youtube.com' without iptables

Any ideas?

Comment: dnsdist is another option. check manual https://dnsdist.org/rules-actions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` alone cannot make decisions based on DNS packet content, only by the address and port numbers on the packet headers. At minimum, you would need an iptables extension [like iptables-ext-dns](https://github.com/mimuret/iptables-ext-dns).

But it seems to me that you might instead want to do *transparent proxying for DNS*: you could set the minipc to *redirect* any outgoing packets going to port 53 (either UDP or TCP) to a DNS server of your choice, and then configure that DNS server to manipulate the answers as you desire. You will be essentially performing a man-in-the-middle attack on all DNS traffic passing through your minipc.

You should also be aware that there are new techniques that aim for cryptographic protection of DNS traffic, like [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) (already supported by Firefox 62 or later) or [DNS over TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_TLS).

If your client uses those, a simple redirect of traffic with destination port 53 won't be able to catch those requests - and even if you take extra steps to catch the traffic, the fact that the apparent DNS-over-whatever server has a different certificate than expected will reveal your manipulation.

Also, you should be aware that [Youtube could be accessed not only as youtube.com, but also as youtu.be and possibly via other domains too.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22148440/9197000)

Comment: well, I am aware of DNS over random stuff exists, was just curious about the old good DNS server. The MITM part seems a nice idea, means forcing clients to being redirected into my DNS, thats what I was looking for. Thanks!